# Check if an element is added on a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid

I have a `UserControl` contained in a class When some conditions are met I initialize the `UserControl` and I add it in a `Grid`, setting row and column property depending on the position of the class in a list. When I change that position, I need to update the position of the element on the Grid, but since not every class has its `UserControl` initialised and added, I need to check when I order the elements in the `Grid`.
To check if the `UserControl` is initialised I check if it is null 
`classElement.userControl == null`

How do I check if the `UserControl` has been added to the `Grid`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this sounds like something, which would be trivial to solve in a an MVVM design involving a ViewModel having an ObservableCollection, where you add/remove items, and an ItemsControl in the View, which is updated accordingly. Any special reason you want to do this in code behind?

Comment: delete all that (probably ugly) code and use an `ItemsControl`. Otherwise post the relevant code and a screenshot of what you need. Close-voting.

Comment: Hehe... I see you're back on form there, my old friend. :)

Comment: I used this approach because I need to show elements in different parts of the UI and with different controls (data behind is the same, but usercontrols are different).The number of elements is dynamic and since I am new to WPF this is what I knew. At the moment, I have a list made of classes, and in the class the data and the usercontrols are stored and uploaded them manually.I know it is not efficient, so if you know the best way to do this please write what solution I can implement (in a way that let me understand what I am supposed to study).Short and half ironic answers are not useful...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way to achieve your requirements would be for you to simply iterate through the children of the `Grid` using the `Children` property, checking each one in turn. You could do something like this:

```
<Grid Name="YourGrid">
    ...
</Grid>
```

...

```
foreach (UIElement uiElement in YourGrid.Children)
{
    if (uiElement.GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
    {
        if (uiElement != null)
        {
            // Do something with your control here
        }
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

I don't understand your comment... you said *I need a way to know if the usercontrol is in the grid or not*... that is exactly what I have provided you with. If you are adding the `UserControl` to the `Grid`, then you must have a reference to the `Grid`. If you have a reference to the `Grid`, then you can iterate the controls that have been added to that `Grid` just as I have shown you. If you are adding the `UserControl` from the `UserControl` code behind, then you can do this:

```
foreach (UIElement uiElement in YourGrid.Children)
{
    if (uiElement.GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
    {
        if (uiElement != null)
        {
            if (uiElement == this)
            {
                // this UserControl is in the Grid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this does not solve you problem, then please take the time to provide a decent description of your problem that would enable me to suggest a fix for it. From what I understand presently, *this* is your fix.

Comment: I control an element through the class that contains it, and I need to access the class' properties to change the position of the element. That's why it is easier to do it directly from a class' method, but I need a way to know if the usercontrol is in the grid or not.
VisialTreeHelper.GetParent == null  could work?

Comment: I have a list with x elements, every element has a UserControl, which might be initialized and added to the grid or not. Since when I add/remove elements I sort the list, I also need to move the UserControls in the Grid, which need to reflect the sequence of the elements in the list. I do this setting the row (I am semplifying) of every UserControl equal to the list index of the element that contains it. Before doing it, I need to check if UserControl is in the grid. 
Your solution might work for me, but it looks quite expensive in term of resources. Isn't there an easier solution?

Comment: @Sheridan doing `foreach` on the Visual Tree? seems like you gave up on teaching the ways of WPF? Don't let yourself down by the numberless hordes of procedural-code devs...

Comment: LOL! While I do accept your point, I was just helping the question author out in ways they would understand and most importantly, *without having to explain how MVVM works*.

Comment: @Sheridan sounds legit. +1 then. ;)

Comment: @Sheridan btw, if you don't feel like explaining MVVM in every single answer you post, you can reference to any of my `...delete all your code and start all over...` answers around... haha

Comment: @Highcore... haha... maybe I will! ;)

Comment: @Hamma, you said *Your solution might work for me, but it looks quite expensive in term of resources.* Are you serious??? My `foreach` loop isn't using any resources, unlike the fact that *you* are holding a collection of elements that can each hold a `UserControl`. Then you said *Isn't there an easier solution?* Again, really? What is easier than a `foreach` loop and a few `if` statements?